# Is there a special character that cannot be typed or copied by user, but can be inserted/read by code into/from text?

Tags: special-characters, delimiter, separator, plaintext

I need to have a temporary delimiter, inserted server-side, that cannot possibly exist in content created by user.

The purpose for this is to have prepared content for CSV export, with configurable value delimiter, that will replace this untypeable character client-side, right before the export.

Does such character even exist?

Comment: @Ðаn What's with the unicode.org? Is there any character there that cannot be copy-pasted?

Comment: Why do you need a single character ?

Comment: @Kaiido To eliminate accidental data integrity breaks and for efficiency ofcourse, why else.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible design. What about `while(data.contains(delimiter)){ delimiter=randomPhrase()}` ? By extending the length of the delimoter you'll get more entropy and less risk of colision. And to answer your question, no, no such single character does exist.

Comment: It will work, but this approach has it's downsides. Having more than one char will increase the file size exponentially and impact page load time for larger content (rows x columns x delimiterchars). Also having to check the existence of the delimiter in the content before generation, will require storing data in memory (for ex: arrays) server-side and having per-column-per-row loop for each try. That's complexity, memory footprint and CPU usage that could be avoided if some special invisible character existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no character that cannot *possibly* exist; however there are many characters (in particular control codes - those lower than decimal 32, excluding cr/lf/tab) that are *extremely unlikely* to exist in any reasonable text content. This is why escaping is often required in text-based protocols. There is no reserved space of characters that will be escaped in CSV, other than those already used in CSV itself.

Comment: Thank you for clarification Marc.

Comment: I used '\0' from the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67214583/6854902

Answer (score 0):

Zero-width joiner is a unicode invisible kind of character which exist but do not exist. You can use that! :)